# Certificate renewed with different subject name

Tags: iis, certificate

There was a certificate expiry in our application and we renewed the certificate. After updating our config files with the new thumbprint there is one service that is failing and as per the event viewer, it is unable to find the renewed certificate.

After comparing it with the old cert, we observed that the subject name is not matching. For the old cert it was

CN = xxx.xxx.xxx

OU = xx.xx.xx

O = xx.xx.xx

L = xx.xx.xx

S = xx

C = XX

The new cert is like this

CN = xxx.xxx.xxx

CN value is same in both the cases. Just the other details like OU, O , L, S and C are missing in the new one. Does these matter when the service is checking for the cert?

Comment: How could we possibly know, since we know nothing about the service except that it's failing?

Comment: Even I am not sure about the code in the service. But the event viewer says that the service is unable to find the cert and the entire Subject name was mentioned in the log. So I was thinking maybe it is using the subject name to search. Ideally, the code would be searching for a cert using the thumbprint provided in the config. I just wanted to know how much a subject name matters in a certificate.

Comment: That's the thing about certificates. The information has to be correct. You should have the certificate re-issued with the correct information.

Answer (score 0):

If your application is behaving like a browser, or using standard SSL libraries, it only cares about the CN (or SubjectAltName) matching the desired hostname.

If your app is accessible publicly, try pointing ssllabs.com's SSL checker at it.  A common issue is a missing / incorrect intermediate certificate, which can break some clients.

It is also possible that your failing client doesn't trust the root cert used to renew the server certificate.

Comment: Actually the issue was resolved after we got the cert with matching subject name.  That indeed was the issue.  Thanks for answering :)